# nbdev and 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I recently updated the nbdev version of an "old" project of mine (I made a new conda environment), and now automatic tests in github (the "Run tests" part of the build) are failing with a

```
'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
```

error per notebook, that seems totally unrelated to my code. There are also a few

```
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

and

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ZMQSocketChannel.get_msg' was never awaited
```

None of this happens when I run `nbdev_test_nbs` locally.

Any clue?

Comment: I am facing this same error as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I faced the very same issue. It turned out that I had `nbconvert` version pinned in my `setup.py`, like `'nbconvert~=5.6.1'`.

After removing this restriction tests started to pass again.

P.S. The version of `nbconvert` is now 6+.

Comment: I don't understand how this could have been the solution, as even nbdev 1.1.21 still requires nbconvert < 6 ?

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue with jupyter-client, see there was a yanked version deployed on the day you reported: https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-client/#history

This thread details the RCA: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/issues/637

This was solved for me by downgrading to `jupyter-client==6.1.12`

Comment: I didn't have `jupyter_client` around, but had this error. In the logs (yours as well) one may see that the source of the error is `nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to "*autograde*" the submissions or "*validate*" my notebooks. For some reason which I do not remember, I downgraded the "*nbconvert*" to 5.6.1 (I think there was an issue). Having this problem, I have upgraded my "nbconvert"  back to 6.5.0 and now I can auto-grade the submissions.

Note: in my other jupyter environment (python 3.6, *nbconvert* 5.6.1, and jupyter-client: 6.1.7), I can both validate and auto-grade the notebooks.